# Is it possible to stick to one of these viewpoints of variables?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

It has been a struggle to find a precise account of the concept of variables. There are however two viewpoints that I've seen authors convey in several logic textbooks.

1. Variables as placeholders for names: Here, in an expression like "x is a monument in Italy", the "x" doesn't refer to anything, it is meaningless. It only occupies a place where it makes sense to have names for monuments all around the world. So, "x" is a placeholder in this sense for names. From this viewpoint even the expression "x is a monument in Italy" would be meaningless, because "x" is meaningless. By meaningless here, I mean, an absolute meaninglessness, like the expression "#$SGR! GW", that doesn't refer to anything, any thought.
2. Variables as names for unspecified things: Here, in an expression like "x is a monument in Italy", the "x" does refer to something, it has a meaning. It refers to a thing among some given things, without referring to any in particular. That is, the referent of "x" is an unspecified thing. It refers to a single thing, that is not specified. From this viewpoint the expression "x is a monument in Italy" has a meaning as well, because "x" has a meaning. The meaning of "x is a monument in Italy" would be that there is a monument x, and that x is in Italy. At all times here, we're referring to the unspecified monument.

My issue is that I'm not able to decide which viewpoint should I accept, to build my further knowledge of anything that involves the use of variables. My motivation to study logic was to equip myself with a precise language that I can use to study other fields. And with variables being so fundamental I feel scared of taking a step ahead with their vague understanding.

**Which viewpoint should one accept, that would be consistent throughout the study of logic and math?**

**Is is possible to stick to one of these viewpoints?**

---

Some scrambled thoughts:

One thing that I often struggle with by accepting variables as in 1., is the concept of bound variables. Seeing an expression  like "For any thing x, P(x)" and by viewing variables as in 1. (i.e. as placeholders for names), makes me want to replace "x" with some name in "For any thing x, P(x)". But I know common understanding is that I can't replace variables by names in expressions that have quantifiers. Then, is it possible to understand bound variables using viewpoint 1.?

There's an advantage that I can see with 2. Since 2. results in expressions using variables as meaningful, I can view these expressions as expressing general thoughts. For instance, I might notice 2+0=2, 3+0=3, 4+0=4, 6+0=6, 10+0=10,..., then in natural language I can say, okay, the sum of a number and 0, is the same as the number itself. Using symbolism, I can say, let "x" denote a natural number (unspecified), then x+0=x can be seen as a general thought about numbers. Whereas if I were to accept 1., "x+0=x" would've been meaningless (because "x" is simply a placeholder for names).

Comment: Variables in formal languages are like pronouns: "x is red" is like "it is red". We need some context to give meaning to the statement, like variable assignment functions used by the semantical specifications for predicate logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA When I say "It is red" in English, I still think of this expression as having a meaning (as in it's different than saying "hukka bukka lopa" which is completely meaningless). "It" refers to an object, unspecified. So, if I draw a parallel between pronouns and variables, variables should be interpreted as in 2. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't believe its accurate to call "x is a monument in Italy" meaningless. It's a predicate which is true or false depending on which x we are considering. The "x" does refer to something, it refers to an element in your domain of discourse. Now, the statement could be false for all x, but the x still refers to a particular variable in your language.

Comment: for Number 2), I believe the term: There exists an x such that.... encapsulates this idea, where x is refereing to some unspecified thing in a list of things.

Comment: Is there any philosophical, scientific or mathematical problem stemming from ambiguity as to what a variable is? If so, a resolution of it may guide you in your quest.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think I've trouble understanding free and bound variables. I cannot see how with the placeholder viewpoint one can see variables as bound. As mentioned in the post, my mind says "why can't I replace it with a name if it's a place holder", whenever a variable is bound in an expression. I've somewhat started to understand bound variables using the second viewpoint. 1. bothers me because it is used in the literature at times and I think I get a FOMO.

Comment: @HarshitRajput I think that writing a few simple formal proofs in predicate logic using some form of natural deduction, will assure you that you are not "missing out" on anything.  You will quickly internalize the difference between free and bound variables and how they are used in proofs.